# How can I increase the stack size for arithmetic operations in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am currently using longs to perform arithmetic operations but the resulting numbers are too large (more than 9223372036854775807) so are causing overflow errors. Is there a way I could increase this cap by either using a different data type or by allowing longs access to more data?

Comment: Depending on what arithmetic operations you're using, you might be able to use [`BigInteger`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot increase the definition of `long`.
However you can use the [BigInteger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx) struct to accomplish your task.
Its limit is practically your computer memory.

The BigInteger struct allows you to use both positive and negative integer values and provides most operations you can also find in the Math class, like `Pow`, `Mod`, but also `ModPow` and addition features like `IsPowerOfTwo` and `IsEven`.

In order to use the BigInteger struct you would need to add a project reference to [System.Numerics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics(v=vs.110).aspx), also it requires .NET Framework 4.0 or higher.

Answer (score 1):

Try using ulong, if you only need a positive number. It will have double the capacity, as there is no sign bit.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Biginteger`.

To use it in your project- Add a reference to the `System.Numerics` assembly to your project.

```
using System.Numerics;
```

For more info refer [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx)